# Strong params working diffently on production than on development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have an issue with my environments.

While I'm on development mode and try to use `params.require(:symbol)` throws an error: `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):` but not in production environment.

I have been looking into web for some help about it, have not found anything. Any of the config environments show any relevant info about it.

How can I have my both environments work the same?.

Comment: I had this problem in my test environment (not development), because I created test data where keys in the params hash were symbols. The keys in your test data have to be strings. I don't know how that would apply in development, but perhaps that gives you an angle to investigate.

Comment: I'm sending my data as json. Does it have something to take into account?. Is it like `Strong params` are not available on my  development environment?

Comment: can you show a sample of your json and params code as well?